# How do I change the color of the span text when it's clicked, and back to normal when clicked again?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code, and I want that when a number is clicked – contained within `<span>` elements – it should change color, and when it's clicked again it should revert back to the original normal. I already found some online tutorials about changing color, and put some of that code to change color when clicked, but when it clicked it changed all the colors, not only the color of the element I wanted to change.

Could you show me how to make this happen, without setting all span with different id or class, because I have around 1000 span like this.

```js
spans = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
for (const span of spans) {
  span.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  span.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", span.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 475px;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

 ::selection {
  background: none
}

span:active {
  color: purple
}
```

```html
<span class="class">444819751</span>
<span class="class">444820170</span>
<span class="class">444820588</span>
```

Comment: It's only affecting one bit of text at a time according to that snippet.

Comment: You want to change just 1 or a specific group of spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just very small change

```js
spans = document.querySelectorAll(".class");

for (const span of spans) {

  span.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  span.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", span.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });

  span.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    if(span.style.color === 'red'){
      span.style.color = 'blue'
    }else {
      span.style.color = 'red'
    }
  });

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 475px;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

 ::selection {
  background: none
}

span:active {
  color: purple
}
```

```html
<span class="class">444819751</span>
<span class="class">444820170</span>
<span class="class">444820588</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i need and what i want :), at before i forget to mention i already write some javascript to do when it clicked it copy that text. and as i see u reading my code before u answear my question. other people answear not put my before code. so it only change color not copy that text

Comment: you are always welcome :) .. good work btw

Answer (score 2):

First you can select your wanted elements with a querySelector and then
you can add a event listener and get the reference of the clicked span like this

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.allowClick span').forEach(occurence => {
  occurence.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.style.color == "red")
      e.target.style.color = "black"
    else
      e.target.style.color = "red"
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="allowClick">
  <span>Allow click</span>
  <span>11111111</span>
  <span>222222222</span>
  <span>AAAAAAAAA</span>
  <span>BBBBBB</span>
  <span>CCCCCC</span>
</div>

<br/>

<div>
  <span>Dont allow click</span>
  <span>11111111</span>
  <span>222222222</span>
  <span>AAAAAAAAA</span>
  <span>BBBBBB</span>
  <span>CCCCCC</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
function changeColor(x) {
  if (x.style.color == "red") {
    x.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    x.style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[1]</span>
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[2]</span>
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[3]</span>
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[4]</span>
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[5]</span>
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[6]</span>
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[7]</span>
<span onclick="changeColor(this)">[8]</span>
```

Comment: "*how to make this happen, without setting all span with different id or class*" - from the question that you're answering, by using an `id` to target the element.